# How to point subdomain to another shared IP adress?

Tags: domain, ip

I've got my nameservers pointed to 1st IP adress.
Is there any way I can point subdomain to a 2nd shared IP adress (hosting)?
It's not that simple to just point subdomain to 2nd IP because the hosting uses multiple virtual apache hostings.

Comment: Please sit back and rewrite your question. It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to edit your DNS table in your dns provider panel (if they give you the way to have subdomains).

You just need to ad a new A record like:

1.2.3.4   A  subdomain.yourdomain.com.

Every dns provider have a specific panel, just looks at other records to do the new one.

If you need a DYNAMIC subdomain redirect, I suggest you to use dyndns.org